# What happens if you fail a quest?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I was skimming through the Stats screen in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* when I came across this puzzling bit of information:

[image]

Personally, I wasn't even aware of the fact that failing a quest was even *possible*. Now, being a completionist, this concept has me worried. I know in [this article](http://www.rpgamer.com/news/Q1-2012/012512b.html), they mentioned being unable to lock yourself out of content. However, I'm worried that failing a quest would conflict with that concept.

**What are the consequences for failing quests?**

Comment: As a completionist, how do you plan to maximize the failed quest counter?

Comment: I uh... Didn't mean it like that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to fail quests.

Firstly, credit to [Sterno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3062/sterno), there are a handful of "1 shot" quests like [Oh, the Indignitaries](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Oh,_The_Indignitaries) 
. It's usually trivia or logic puzzle quests that have this condition that I've encountered.

Secondly, you may fail a quest if a quest NPC dies. As you probably know, you can turn on Hostile Mode and attack friendly NPCs. Besides main storyline NPCs, I've found that pretty much everything is fair game, and you can completely lock yourself out of certain quest lines by killing respective quest NPCs.

Thirdly... (pretty big spoiler here)

> You can lock yourself out of certain faction quests through betrayal. For example, towards the end of the Warsworn main quest line, you may choose to betray them. By doing so, any remaining quests you have with their faction will immediately fail as the NPCs are irreversibly hostile towards you.

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine. Deleting mine!

Comment: @Sterno Updated my answer then, credit where it's due.

Comment: So much for their statement saying that any choices wouldn't lock the player out of content.

Comment: @Tristan I think their original statement was directed, albeit not explicitly, to the choice of "simply doing a quest will not directly lock you out of another quest" such that quests are not mutually exclusive. Very grey area though, I will admit.